# What does "Retain information about dependencies in the apk/bundle" do in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

[image: Project Structure Window]In the "Project Structure" window, there are two dropdown boolean options:

1. Retain information about dependencies in the apk
2. Retain information about dependencies in the bundle

What do these options do? What is the recommended setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting it to `true` changes in `build.gradle.ts` the entry

```
android {
    dependenciesInfo {
        includeInApk = true
    }
}
```

According to the documentation of [includeInApk](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/DependenciesInfo#includeinapk) it has the effect:

> If false, information about SDK dependencies of an APK will not be added to its signature block.

In the source code of [DependenciesInfo.kt](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/refs/heads/mirror-goog-studio-main/build-system/gradle-api/src/main/java/com/android/build/api/dsl/DependenciesInfo.kt) there are some additional info:

> Including dependency information in your APK or Bundle allows Google
> Play to ensure that any third-party software your app uses complies with  [Google Play's Developer Program Policies](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/topic/9858052).
>
> For more information, see the Play Console support page [Using third-party SDKs in your
> app](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10358880).

Comment: Thank you! But what is the recommended setting? Can you name a few SDKs as example where I might need to turn this setting on?

Comment: @RezaHajianpour Sorry I don't publish apps in Play Store so I don't know which third party software Google is referring to. One possibility I can imagine are apps for children. Especially in the US there are restrictions for children under 13 what you are not allowed to do (not sure something like tracking frameworks?). So may be Google enforces you to publish the used frameworks for this type of apps, but that is just a guess...

Comment: And IMHO the recommended setting is leave it default (which is false) unless Google wants you to enable it when you try to release an app.

Comment: My default setting in Android Studio is unset. Is false the default value in gradle? If so you've answered my question and I'll mark it as such